# Turning off screen the same way Windows does it

Tags: c#, winapi, user32

Before you ask, no, this is not a duplicate. At least not to my knowledge. To explain why, please continue reading.

The following code can be used to turn off the screen, and it does work in my case:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, [Out] IntPtr lParam);
 
public void TurnOffScreen()
{
    PostMessage(new IntPtr(0xFFFF), 0x0112, (IntPtr)0xF170, (IntPtr)2);
}
```

In Windows, you have an option called "Turn off my screen after" followed by a dropdown ranging from 1 minute to 5 hours (or never). When the screen turns off using that, it's not the same as my piece of code. How did I determine that? Well, take a look at the following code:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

public void TurnOnScreen()
{
    mouse_event(0x0001, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    mouse_event(0x0001, 0, -1, 0, 0);
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    MousePoint mousePoint = GetCursorPosition();
    mouse_event(0x0002 | 0x0004, mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y, 0, 0);
}
```

That code will move the cursor 1 pixel, twice, then press and release the mouse. This is done to simulate user input, so the screen wakes up.

One major issue is, the above code only works when the screen is turned off automatically by Windows. I've gotten it to work unreliably a few times when I turned off the screen with the first piece of code, but I'm guessing it's pure luck.

Does anybody know how Windows turns off the screen, when the timer has expired? Does it just set the brightness to 0%? Does it call a different method with different values? I want to replicate that exact behavior, so I can programmably turn off the screen.

Comment: I'm guessing it's done using the power API, based on the fact that my monitors go into power-saving mode for quite a while rather than actually turning off.

Comment: @KenWhite And that would make sense, because that's what mine does as well. So I think that rules out the "set brightness to 0%".

Comment: I think the question is how to wake the screen with the right power management API, which I don't know by the way. The system probably doesn't use fake mouse move to wake the screen.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `PostMessage(new IntPtr(0xFFFF), 0x0112, (IntPtr)0xF170, (IntPtr)-1);` to power it back on? If that doesn't work, then try using a larger pixel number -- like 10 instead of 1.

Comment: Note sure it changes anything to your original question but you shouldn't use HWND_BROADCAST, have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68947055/403671 Also why don't use use names instead of raw values, it's easier to search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SC_MONITORPOWER

Comment: Posting a message to a unknown destination is always going to be unreliable.