# Turning off the screen bat freezes the applications

Tags: c#, windows, screen, .net-4.8, system.timers.timer

I have a problem with my app.

The application is designed to perform certain tasks periodically.
If it deems it necessary, it must turn off the screen, but it still has to carry out its tasks.
Unfortunately, when the screen turns off, the application stops working. It is as if frozen.
When the screen is turned on (e.g. by clicking a button on the keyboard), the application becomes active again and works properly.
Freezing the application blocks threads, tasks, and even Timers, and freezes completely.

I turn off the screen by calling:

```
SendMessage (-1, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr) SC_MONITORPOWER, (IntPtr) newState);
```

The application is written in C# .NET Framework 4.8.
Windows 10 Enterpraise LTSC (1809)
Screen lock, screensaver, user logout, etc. is disabled.

Screen is using with eDP.

This problem is on UpBoard computer, it is one-board PC.
On different a laptop, the application works without any problems.

Comment: Don't use -1 HWND, use a real window.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946250/turn-off-the-monitor-in-windows ?

Comment: @Anders: -1 in HWND it is not problem...  screen is off, bat problem is: system froze application.

Comment: Allow me to quote Raymond Chen on using -1 to turn off the monitor (linked in the linked answer): "Making up intentionally invalid parameters and seeing what happens falls into the category of malicious goofing around, not in the realm of software engineering and design. Even if you find something that seems to work, you certainly wouldn’t design a product around it!" "If you look more carefully at what the author stumbled across, you’ll see that the “solution” is actually another **bug**. It so happens that the numerical value -1 for a window handle is suspiciously close to the value of ..."

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved!
Problem is from Windosw suspend mode.
I must disable modern suspend mode!